# C++ Class Design - how to clean up in base-class destructor

Tags: c++, oop, virtual, feedback

I have trouble thinking outside the box with the following issue. I have a class hierarchy:

`[BaseClass] --> [Win32Class]`

`[BaseClass] --> [LinuxClass]`

`[BaseClass] --> [VxWorksClass]`

The implementation classes will make calls to API-level functions. These are done inside pure virtual functions from the base class.

Now, when the user creates, uses and is finished with the object, he should call the `Done` function (from base class), which will do cleanup and resource de-allocation. Part of this cleanup is to call a number of API-level functions -- these naturally are pure virtuals in the base class and implemented in the derived classes. So far so good.

Here's the problem. If the user **does not** explicitly call `Done` there will be various memory leaks due to resources not being properly freed. So, I figured I'd make it easy and call `Done` from `~BaseClass()` - automatic cleanup on destruction, i thought. Well, not so much. Since `Done` makes calls to these pure virtuals all hell breaks loose.

Any thoughts on how to re-design this to avoid this issue?

example code

```
class BaseClass{ 
  virtual ~BaseClass(){
    Done();
  }
  void Done(){
    // A bunch of OS-independent clean-up logic
    Cleanup();
    // some more OS-independent clean-up logic
  }
  virtual void Cleanup() = 0;
};
class Win32Class : public BaseClass{
  virtual void Cleanup(){
    // call some Win32-specific cleanup code
  }
};
class LinuxClass : public BaseClass{
  virtual void Cleanup(){
    // call some Linux-specific cleanup code
  }
};
```

==========================================
Here's my solution. Use a wrapper class. Don;t call `Done` in the destructor of `Win32Class` or `BaseClass`

```
class Win32Wrapper{
public:
  Win32Class* object_;
public:
  Win32Wrapper(){
    this->object_ = new Win32Class;
  }
  ~Win32Wrapper(){
    this->object_->Done();
    delete this->object_;
  }
};
```

== How to Call Pure Virtuals in a destructor ==

```
class Base{
public:
  Base(){
  }
  virtual ~Base(){
    Done();
  }
  void Done(){
    Clean();
  }
  virtual void Clean() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:  
  Derived(){
  }
  ~Derived(){
  }
  virtual void Clean(){
  }
};
```

The user thinks that the program will work, because the compiler doesn't complain about the call to a PFV in `Base::Done()`.

Comment: Without seeing some example code, it's difficult to say exactly. I suspect, though, that you need to make `~BaseClass()` virtual.

Comment: @Code-Guru: That has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB As I said, I don't know for sure and was making a guess. Thanks for clarifying that I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I added some example code for you (and all) @Code-Guru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the clean-up code in the derived destructors:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() { }

    void CleanUp() { /* ... */ }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        CleanUp();
    }
};
```

If you want, you can even put calls to further virtuals into the non-virtual `Base::CleanUp()` function to allow for derived-specific behaviour (though by your description it sounds like you don't need that).

Comment: I don't see how this helps anything (but I don't understand the problem, either).

Comment: This is how I had it implemented. However. And yes, In my case the `CleanUp` function will be making calls to pure virtuals derived from Base, and implemented in Derived - which causes bad things to happen.

Comment: I take that back that was NOT the way I had it implemented first. I had the `virtual ~Base` calling `Cleanup` which I assume caused the havoc -- then i moved the Cleanup call to the `~Derived` function and removed it from the `~Base` - which is what you suggested as well.

Comment: So i guess there's no way around it then... The user HAS to **explicitly** call `Done()` when the object is about to be destroyed?

Comment: @Piotr What bad things happened?

Comment: @Piotr: the whole point is to make the calls in the *derived* destructors.

Comment: Done is implemented in BaseClass it makes pure virtual calls. Therefore if Done is called from DerivedClass's destructor, it will call into oblivion calling the pure virtuals.

Comment: @Piotr: You can't "make a pure virtual call". That makes no sense.

Comment: @Piotr: Don't blame your "teachers" -- I think you're just misunderstanding something. Mind you, "calling virtual functions in a constructor" is something different from "calling a pure virtual function". I'm only saying that the latter doesn't really make sense, and it is actually very hard to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? `calling a pure virtual function ...  doesn't really make sense, and it is actually very hard to do` I'm not following at all at this point...

Comment: Please refer to my OP for an example of calling pure virtuals in a destructor. Code here didn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the RAII idiom is what you are looking for.

You can find a quite comprehensive description of this here: http://www.hackcraft.net/raii/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. The user of `BaseClass` has to call `Done()`, and any bugs due to not doing it are his responsibility.
2. Each of the derived classes performs whatever cleanup is needed in their destroctors. They can use `BaseClass` functions in their cleanup, and the `BaseClass` functions can even call functions that are overridden by the derived class.